# PHP preg_match_all, check & explode

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I want to check 'n' explode this string:

```
{$gallery#pager/collectionName/imageName/manual/no_effect/foo1/foo2/.../fooN}
```

to:

```
var_name[0] => 'gallery',
modul_name[0] => 'pager',
3[0] => 'collectionName',
4[0] => 'imageName',
5[0] => 'manual'
...
N[0] => 'fooN'
```

I made the following regexp:

```
/{\$(?P<var_name>[^#]+)#(?P<module_name>[^\/]+)(?:\/(\w+)(?:\/(\w+)(?:\/(\w+)(?:\/(\w+)(?:\/(\w+))?)?)?)?)?}/
```

, but it's too ugly and only support up to five parameters.
Please help me to make a recursive part to extract all parameters.

ps: Yes, i can split this to **var_name**, **module_name** and **paramters** parts, then i can explode **parameters** part by '/', but i don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

**Regex:**

```
preg_split('@([$#])|[{}/]+@', $text)
```

And discard the first and third item in the array.

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/efpYx9)</kbd>

---

---

***EDIT:*** To reflect new conditions specified by the OP in comments (not in the question): It should validate the syntax `^\{\$\w+#\w+(?:/\w*)$` and tokenize in *var*, *module* and *parameters* independently.

**Regex:**

```
~\G(?(?=^)\{\$(\w++)#(\w++)(?=[\w/]+}$))/\K\w*+~
```

- <kbd>`\G`</kbd> Matches at the [beggining of string or at the end of last match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).
- <kbd>`(?(?=^) ... )`</kbd> [If](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) at start of string
- <kbd>`\{\$(\w++)#(\w++)(?=[\w/]+}$`</kbd> Capture var and module, and validate syntax until the end of string.
- <kbd>`/\K`</kbd> Match 1 slash and [reset matched text](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).
- <kbd>`\w*+`</kbd> Match 1 parameter.

**Code:**

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/32969465/5290909

$pattern = '@\G(?(?=^)\{\$(\w++)#(\w++)(?=[\w/]+}$))/\K\w*+@';
$text = '{$gallery#pager/collectionName/imageName/manual/no_effect/foo1/foo2/fooN}';

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

if ($result === 0) {
    // is invalid, does not match '~^\{\$\w+#\w+(?:/\w*)+$~'
    echo "Invalid text";
} else {
    // Assign vars (only to clarify)
    $module_name = array_pop($matches)[0];
    $var_name = array_pop($matches)[0];
    $parameters = $matches;

    echo "VAR NAME: \t'$var_name'\nMODULE:  \t'$module_name'\nPARAMETERS:\n";
    print_r($matches);
}
```

**Output:**

```
VAR NAME:   'gallery'
MODULE:     'pager'
PARAMETERS:
Array
(
    [0] => collectionName
    [1] => imageName
    [2] => manual
    [3] => no_effect
    [4] => foo1
    [5] => foo2
    [6] => fooN
)
```

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/rbct2l)</kbd>

Comment: Right, but isn't validate it.

Comment: Please specify what exactly needs to be validated in your question

Comment: `{$var_name#module_name}` - this format required. Arguments are optional: `{$var_name#module_name/arg1/arg2/.../argN}` All names and values (var name, module name, arguments) are checkable by \w+.

Comment: It's ok, but in this approach i can use pattern `{\$(\w+)#(\w+)(?:\/([\w|\/]+))?}`, which already validate, and next step i can explode `$match[3]` by `/`. But i'm too OCD for this. :)

Comment: Thanks, sorry was inaccuracy (and bad english, if it was :)).

Answer (score 2):

```
{\$([^#]+)#|\G(?!^)([^\/]+)\/|\G(?!^)(.*?)}$
```

You can simply do a match instead and grab the `groups`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/18

```
$re = "/{\\$([^#]+)#|\\G(?!^)([^\\/]+)\\/|\\G(?!^)(.*?)}$/m"; 
$str = "{\$gallery#pager/collectionName/imageName/manual/no_effect/foo1/foo2/.../fooN}"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: 1) Super, thx. I will use `{\$([^#]+)#([^\/]+)|\G(?!^)(\/[^\/]+)}`, because var_name ($1) and module_name ($2) are required.
2/a) matches[3] indexed from 1. Why?
2/b) what is this \G(?!^) ? I can't google this. :(